# opencart 1.5.6.4 Can't login fresh install

Tags: opencart

I just installed opencart 1.5.6.4.
The install went smooth but when I try to login with the right user and password it just refreshes the page and and I can see a token in the url. I tried to google for a solution but went up with empty hands. Now I'm asking you guys, do you have any idea for how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please, take a [tour](https://stackoverflow/tour) or look into the [help](https://stackoverflow/help) section to find out how a good question is asked. Yours - without an improvement - is probably going to be closed. **Hint**: it is missing important info on how to identify and fix the problem. Maybe a link to your admin with demo user credentials could be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your URLS in the config file remove www also delete your .htaccess file make a backup of this file just in case before you delete it . The server should recreate a new .htaccess